# How to add a Custom button on EmailMessage record page?

Tags: custom-button, emailmessage

I'm trying to add a button on a record page of EmailMessage sobject. This button have to open LWC. I've already realized that it is impossible to add quick action. But several articles claim that it is possible to add custom button. But for some reason custom button doesn't show up on my record page either.
So, do you know, is it possible to add Custom button and what mistake did I make?
[image: Custom button configuration]

[image: Custom button added on page layout]

[image: all buttons that i see in a result]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved this problem. It is possible to add Custom button on EmailMessage record page - just need to put it in a right section on page layout. But.
If you need to open lwc on EmailMessage record page by clicking on the button, you should create Screen Flow with LWC inside and choose it in quick action. For some reason, quick action with flow inside is supported on the record page.